# Error during installation of snort in Fedora 31.Any solutions?

Tags: linux, fedora, snort, ids

- /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libdnet: file not recognized: Is a
  directory collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make[6]: ***
  [Makefile:486: libsf_sorules.la] Error 1 make[6]: Leaving directory
  '/usr/src/snort-2.9.15.1/src/dynamic-plugins/sf_engine/examples'
  make[5]:**  [Makefile:623: all-recursive] Error 1 make[5]: Leaving
  directory '/usr/src/snort-2.9.15.1/src/dynamic-plugins/sf_engine'
  make[4]:  **[Makefile:522: all] Error 2 make[4]: Leaving directory
  '/usr/src/snort-2.9.15.1/src/dynamic-plugins/sf_engine' make[3]:** 
  [Makefile:439: all-recursive] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory
  '/usr/src/snort-2.9.15.1/src/dynamic-plugins' make[2]: 
  **[Makefile:547: all-recursive] Error 1 make[2]: Leaving directory
  '/usr/src/snort-2.9.15.1/src' make[1]: *** [Makefile:505:
  all-recursive] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory
  '/usr/src/snort-2.9.15.1' make: *** [Makefile:370: all] Error 2

  - Heading

  =======

Comment: *snort* is available as a Fedora 31 package, in this repo : https://forensics.cert.org/fedora/cert/31/x86_64/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .... installation of snort in Fedora 31

Enable the "cert-forensics-tools.repo" for Fedora 31 https://forensics.cert.org/

```
# rpm -Uvh https://forensics.cert.org/cert-forensics-tools-release-31.rpm
```

Install snort

```
# dnf install snort
```

Provides snort version 2.9.15.1-1.fc31